# pandas fillna inplace with multiindex

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe with  multiindex

```
       values                            observations
time       x1    x2    x3    x4   ...         x1    x2    x3    x4    ...

  t1     v1_1   nan  v3_1  v4_1   ...       o1_1   nan  o3_1  o4_1    ...
  t2     v1_2  v2_2   nan  v4_2   ...       o1_2  o2_2   nan  o4_2    ...
```

I am trying to fillna the observations frame with 0s

```
df.loc[:,('observations')].fillna(value=0, inplace=True)
```

But this does not fill the df. When I take a slice and apply fillna, it works

```
dfx = df.loc[:,('observations')].fillna(value=0)
```

dfx has its nans replaced by 0s and I can replace the original part

```
df.observations = dfx
```

It is not clear to me why the first approach would not work. Seems odd. Could anyone enlighten me here?

Comment: I think problem is `loc` doesnt work inplace. So if use `df1 = df.loc[:,('observations')]` and `df1.fillna(value=0, inplace=True)` it can works.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For me works:

```
df['observations'] = df['observations'].fillna(0)
print (df)
   values                   observations                  
     time    x1    x2    x3           x4    x1    x2    x3
t1   v1_1   NaN  v3_1  v4_1         o1_1     0  o3_1  o4_1
t2   v1_2  v2_2   NaN  v4_2         o1_2  o2_2     0  o4_2
```

**I think problem is `loc` doesnt work inplace.** So you can use:

```
df1 = df.loc[:,('observations')] 
df1.fillna(value=0, inplace=True)
```

Another solution is selecting by `slicing`, but need first sort columns names by [`sort_index`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.sort_index.html):

```
df.sort_index(inplace=True, axis=1)
idx = pd.IndexSlice
df.loc[:, idx['observations',:]] = df.loc[:, idx['observations',:]].fillna(0)
print (df)
     observations                   values                  
time           x1    x2    x3    x4     x1    x2    x3    x4
t1           o1_1     0  o3_1  o4_1   v1_1   NaN  v3_1  v4_1
t2           o1_2  o2_2     0  o4_2   v1_2  v2_2   NaN  v4_2
```

Comment: Thanks. I edited your answer and copied in your above comment, so that I can accept it.